# VBScript to check for open process by user

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, process, wmi

I need a VBScript that will check if a process is in use by a specific user:

Agent clicks program icon --> batch file calls for progcheck.vbs -->

progcheck.vbs looks to see is "whatever.exe" is running under that user only -->

if program is running under that user then MsgBox "Program running" --> wscript.quit (this needs to terminate out of the batch file)

else --> return to batch file.

I have tried this with tasklist in a batch file and the script works, but takes forever to run for a domain user.  Want to do this in vbscript anyway.

*** *UPDATED SCRIPT WITH MODS 10/12* *******

```
OPTION EXPLICIT

    DIM strComputer,strProcess, strUserName,wshShell

    Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
    strUserName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERNAME%" )

    strComputer = "." ' 
    strProcess = "notepad.exe"


    IF isProcessRunning(strComputer,strProcess,strUserName) THEN
            If MsgBox ("Notepad needs to be closed.", 1) = 1 then
                wscript.Quit(1)
            End If
    END IF

FUNCTION isProcessRunning(BYVAL strComputer,BYVAL strProcessName,BYVAL strUserName)

    DIM objWMIService, strWMIQuery

    strWMIQuery = "Select * from Win32_Process where name like '" & strProcessName & "' AND owner like '" &strUserName& "'" 

    SET objWMIService = GETOBJECT("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
            & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 


    IF objWMIService.ExecQuery(strWMIQuery).Count > 0 THEN
        isProcessRunning = TRUE
    ELSE
        isProcessRunning = FALSE
    END If

End Function
```

Let me know what you think and where I have it wrong.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATED CODE v3: *review comments for help***

```
OPTION EXPLICIT

    DIM strComputer, strProcess, strUserName, wshShell

    Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
    strUserName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERNAME%" )
    strComputer = "."
    strProcess = "notepad.exe" 'change this to whatever you are trying to detect

    IF isProcessRunning(strComputer, strProcess, strUserName) THEN
        If MsgBox ("Notepad needs to be closed.", 1) = 1 then
            wscript.Quit(1) 'you need to terminate the process if that's your intention before quitting
        End If
    Else
        msgbox ("Process is not running") 'optional for debug, you can remove this
    END IF

FUNCTION isProcessRunning(ByRef strComputer, ByRef strProcess, ByRef strUserName)

    DIM objWMIService, strWMIQuery, objProcess, strOwner, Response

    strWMIQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE NAME = '" & strProcess & "'"

    SET objWMIService = GETOBJECT("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2").ExecQuery(strWMIQuery)

    IF objWMIService.Count > 0 THEN
        msgbox "We have at least ONE instance of Notepad"
        For Each objProcess in objWMIService
            Response = objProcess.GetOwner(strOwner)
            If Response <> 0 Then
                'we didn't get any owner information - maybe not permitted by current user to ask for it
                Wscript.Echo "Could not get owner info for process [" & objProcess.Name & "]" & VBNewLine & "Error: " & Return
            Else 
                Wscript.Echo "Process [" & objProcess.Name & "] is owned by [" & strOwner & "]" 'for debug you can remove it
                if strUserName = strOwner Then
                    msgbox "we have the user who is running notepad"
                    isProcessRunning = TRUE
                Else
                    'do nothing as you only want to detect the current user running it
                    isProcessRunning = FALSE
                End If
            End If
        Next
    ELSE
        msgbox "We have NO instance of Notepad - Username is Irrelevant"
        isProcessRunning = FALSE
    END If

End Function
```

You can use the following function:

```
FUNCTION isProcessRunning(BYVAL strComputer,BYVAL strProcessName)

    DIM objWMIService, strWMIQuery

    strWMIQuery = "Select * from Win32_Process where name like '" & strProcessName & "'"

    SET objWMIService = GETOBJECT("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
            & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 


    IF objWMIService.ExecQuery(strWMIQuery).Count > 0 THEN
        isProcessRunning = TRUE
    ELSE
        isProcessRunning = FALSE
    END IF

END FUNCTION
```

For local computer you would use `"."`

For the process name, you would use the executable `"notepad.exe"`

For the rest of the code, you could can use something simple:

```
OPTION EXPLICIT
DIM strComputer,strProcess

strComputer = "." ' local computer
strProcess = "notepad.exe" 'whatever is the executable

IF isProcessRunning(strComputer,strProcess) THEN
    'do something
ELSE
    'do something else or nothing
    wscript.echo strProcess & " is NOT running on computer '" & strComputer & "'"
END IF
```

That should do it.

**EXTRA**

To show every process running, then just run:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objWMIService, objProcess, colProcess
Dim strComputer, strList

strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
& strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Process")

For Each objProcess in colProcess
    strList = strList & vbCr & _
    objProcess.Name
Next

WSCript.Echo strList
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Spot on and almost perfect.  I was able to expand on this and complete my script.  I still have one more debug error to get past but I have the rest of it down and working.  Thanks for the massive lead, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You are very welcome. If there is something that you still need, let me know and I will try to debug it for you. Otherwise, I am glad it helped.

Comment: Ok, one last problem....I need to verify the running program for a specific user on a terminal server.  So if a specific user is already running notepad.exe the script needs to check for that and then tell them if it is already running under that user.

Comment: This is my expanded script.  I see pulling the current username and then passing it to the function.  I am a little fuzzy at this point.  I believe I should be able to search the running processes in the query by username.

Comment: That's fine, it looks good but there is an error with the query, so I am debugging it, I will post the working code in a bit.

Comment: @user2872829 Posted the update, your error was the misuse of `LIKE` and also adding the `owner` improperly. I fixed the code and posted it as update with some comments to help you understand.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ - I see the changes, however, I don't see where it is checking for the process by username.  This is going to be running on a terminal server and there will be other users running the same program.  I need to check if the user activating the program is not already running it.  That was the reason for the username check in my code.

Comment: @JBLSR, the script in its current incarnation does not check for the username, because the use of `LIKE` makes it an invalid query. But if you need that and your explanation is clear, I can modify it to include the user check as well. Give me a few and I will post an update.

Comment: @JBLSR, updated code posted, enjoy. Let me know if anything else.

Comment: Excellent and thank you very much.  I was able to modify and adapt the script to my overall process and it works perfectly.  I appreciate all your help.

Comment: @JBLSR, you are most welcome. I am glad it helped you. The foundation is there so you just need to remove the debug items and replace the generic stuff with the specifics you need, which seems you have, and voila you get what you need. Use it in good health and take care.

Answer (score 0):

in terminal server this function can be very slow, all the GetOwner calls are terrible in performance.

A **very fast** **solution** i created is to narrow the query using SessionID of the current user (assuming we want only current user's processes) So I added this code:

SessionID can be obtained this way:

```
Dim oExec, sOutput, iUserPos, iUserLen, iStatePos, SessionID
dim oShell, userName

Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
userName = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%")

Set oExec = oShell.Exec("query session %username%")
sOutput = LCase(oExec.StdOut.ReadAll)
iUserPos = InStr(sOutput, LCase(userName))
iStatePos = InStr(sOutput, "active")
iUserLen = Len(userName)

SessionID = CInt(Trim(Mid(sOutput, iUserPos+iUserLen, iStatePos-iUserPos-iUserLen)))
```

Changed the function from the previous post:

```
Function isProcessRunning(ByRef strComputer, ByRef strProcess, ByRef strUserName, byRef sessionID)
    DIM objWMIService, strWMIQuery, objProcess, strOwner, Response

    strWMIQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE SessionId = " & sessionID & " And NAME = '" & strProcess & "'"

    SET objWMIService = GETOBJECT("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2").ExecQuery(strWMIQuery)

    IF objWMIService.Count > 0 THEN
        'msgbox "We have at least ONE instance of Notepad"
        For Each objProcess in objWMIService
            Response = objProcess.GetOwner(strOwner)
            If Response = 0 Then
                'Wscript.Echo "Process [" & objProcess.Name & "] is owned by [" & strOwner & "]" 'for debug you can remove it
                if strUserName = strOwner Then
                    'msgbox "we have the user who is running notepad"
                    isProcessRunning = TRUE
                Else
                    'do nothing as you only want to detect the current user running it
                    isProcessRunning = FALSE
                End If
                'else 
                 'we didn't get any owner information - maybe not permitted by current user to ask for it
                 'Wscript.Echo "Could not get owner info for process [" & objProcess.Name & "]" & VBNewLine & "Error: " & Return
            End If
        Next
    ELSE
        'msgbox "We have NO instance of Notepad - Username is Irrelevant"
        isProcessRunning = FALSE
    END If

End Function
```