# VB Script: How to tell if a program is already running?

Tags: vbscript, rds

I am writing a script to open an RDP session, but I want to check to see if an RDP session is already running.  My initial thought is to check for MSTSC.EXE running in memory. Any idea how to do this?

Open to alternative solutions for the problem as well. Trying to prevent a client from logging into an RDS server twice. Multiple logins are allowed because the same user may log in from different clients.

Comment: [VBScript to check for open process by user](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19328981/995714)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm currently using this function.

Just call it like this `IsProcessRunning "compname","mstsc.exe"`

```
Function IsProcessRunning( strComputer, strProcess )
    Dim Process, strObject
    IsProcessRunning = False
    strObject   = "winmgmts://" & strComputer
    For Each Process in GetObject( strObject ).InstancesOf( "win32_process" )
    If UCase( Process.name ) = UCase( strProcess ) Then
        IsProcessRunning = True
        Exit Function
    End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks.